# Filestream and windows user permissions

Tags: c#, windows, file-permissions

I.m creating a .jpg file by writing into a filestream:

```
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    fs.Write(image, 0, image.Length);
                }
```

The problem I have is that under certain circumstances the file is created with wrong access permissions, more exactly it seems not to have any owner. "Unable to display current owner." under advanced security settings. The only thing that should be different is the content itself. 
What am I doing wrong? Where are the access rights set when using a FileStream?

Here is the entire code

```
       public void SaveImage(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            //Get the files data
            List<byte[]> files = GetFiles();

            if (files.Count == 0)
                throw new Exception("No data");

            //Calculate the path name
            string FileDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
            if (FileDirectory.Length > 0)
                FileDirectory += "\\";

            string FileNameBase = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
            string FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(path);
            string FinalFileName = "";

            if (files.Count == 1)
            {
                FinalFileName = FileDirectory + FileNameBase + FileExtension;
                while (File.Exists(FinalFileName))
                {
                    FileNameBase = FileNameBase + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
                    FinalFileName = FileDirectory + FileNameBase + FileExtension;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                FinalFileName = FileDirectory + FileNameBase + "(1)" + FileExtension;
                while (File.Exists(FinalFileName))
                {
                    FileNameBase = FileNameBase + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
                    FinalFileName = FileDirectory + FileNameBase + "(1)" + FileExtension;
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
            {
                byte[] image = files[i];
                if (files.Count > 1)
                    FinalFileName = FileDirectory + FileNameBase + "(" + (i + 1).ToString() + ")" + FileExtension;
                else
                    FinalFileName = FileDirectory + FileNameBase + FileExtension;

                if (image.Length == 0)
                    throw new Exception("No data");

                //Store the image in the specified path
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(FinalFileName, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    fs.Write(image, 0, image.Length);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (FaultException<string> ex)
        {
            throw new SdkException(ex.Message, ex.Code, ex.Detail);
        }
        catch (FaultException ex)
        {
            throw new SdkException(ex.Message, ex.Code, "");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Seems that I found the cause of the problem. The permissions of the folder where I wanted to create the new file. I deleted and re-created the folder and now it works. What I still don't understand is why this behaviour and why I didn't receive any exception.

Comment: The file had an owner, it's just that the permissions on the file didn't allow you to see who the owner was.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you get an exception when the file is not created a good way? Here you can find more information regarding file system rights:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights.aspx

Comment: No, there is no exception, the file seems to be created correctly.

Comment: And the access rights should be the default ones, I can't see any line of code handling permissions explicitly.